# Tkinter widget for managing .ini files through ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, configuration

### A tkinter widget for reading/editing .ini files

Dynamically generates a form based on the contents of the passed .ini file.

[image: screenshot]

#### Why make this?

I made this as a backend for a [larger project](https://github.com/teauxfu/pct-scalewiz/); I wanted my user to be able to manage persisted settings in an .ini file without having to find the file or use an external editor.
I also didn't want to have to make a new frontend if the contents of that .ini file change (add/remove sections, etc.).

I don't actively collaborate with anyone else, but I am trying to develop good coding practices while self-teaching. Writing familiar, meaningful docstrings is a goal of mine.

#### Why post?

I want to improve.
I would appreciate any criticisms, even 'it's ugly and I hate it.' This seems like a fairly niche use-case, so my primary area of concern is probably 'is this code legible?' in terms of logical structure.
I feel like the way I chose to handle 'whether or not the program is running in demo mode' is a little awkward/hackey.

#### The code (~270 lines)

```
"""A Tkinter widget to read/write ConfigParser objects from/to .ini files.

Uses a demo dict for example purposes if run as __main__
To change some of the GUI elements dynamically change a
instance._attribute, and call instance.build
Args:
    * parent : the Tkinter parent
    * configpath : absolute path to config file to be edited, default is None
    * _title : title to use for the Toplevel, default is ' '
    * defaultdict : dict to use when resetting form to default values
Class variables:
    * ConfigManager.DEFAULT_DICT : used as fallback if a defaultdict isn't
     passed; can be changed
Methods:
    * ConfigManager.build(dict) -> None: rebuild form using the passed dict
    * ConfigManager.reset_config() -> None: rebuild form using the defaultdict
    * ConfigManager.save_config() -> None: scrapes the form into a ConfigParser
     object and saves it to configpath if one was given
    * ConfigManager.as_dict(ConfigParser) -> dict : returns ConfigParser object
     as a dict
Notes:
    * tries to treat very long dict values as lists if they contain commas;
     the contents are returned to string when writing to file. see line 146
Version: [0.1.0] - 2020-4-30
Author: https://github.com/teauxfu
Gist: https://gist.github.com/teauxfu/bfe19a82381461771c87e2d1a4113355
"""

    import configparser
    import os
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import scrolledtext, ttk


    class ConfigManager(tk.Toplevel):
        # used if one isn't passed to the instance
        DEFAULT_DICT = {
            'section1': {'key1': 'value1',
                 'key2': 'value2',
                 'key3': 'value3'},
            'section2': {'keyA': 'valueA',
                 'keyB': 'valueB',
                 'keyC': 'valueC'},
            'section3': {'foo': 'x',
                 'bar': 'y',
                 'baz': 'z'}
        }

def __init__(
    self, parent,
    configpath=None, _title=' ', defaultdict=None
):
    """Initializes a new ConfigManager.
        * parent: should be a Tkinter object
        * configpath =  an absolute path to the config file
        * _title: optional, the Toplevel's title
        * defaultdict: dict to use when resetting defaults
         uses a demo dict for defaults if one isn't passed.
    """
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.minsize(400, 370)  # big enough to hold the DEFAULT_DICT
    self.configpath = configpath  # to config.ini
    if not self.configpath is None:
        self.configpath = os.path.normpath(configpath)
    self.window_title  = _title  # title of the Toplevel
    self.defaultdict = defaultdict
    if defaultdict is None:
        self.defaultdict = ConfigManager.DEFAULT_DICT

    # ------------------------Widget options-------------------------------
    # the string length threshold for using Entry/Text widget
    self.max_entry_length = 65
    self.text_width = 28  # width of text widgets
    self.text_height = 10  # height of text widgets
    self.entry_width = 40  # width of entry widgets
    self.label_width = 15  # width of label widgets
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    # assess the parser dict
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    try:
        parser.read(self.configpath)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Using the defaultdict instead")
        parser.read_dict(self.defaultdict)
    finally:
        parser_dict = self.as_dict(parser)
        self.build(parser_dict)

def build(self, parser_dict: dict) -> None:
    """Dynamically populates GUI from the contents of parser_dict"""
    try:
        self.container.destroy()
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("Tried to destroy the window's container before it was made")

    self.parser_dict = parser_dict
    self._fields = []  # list of the input widgets from every section
    self._sections = self.parser_dict.keys()  # list of all the sections
    self._section_keys = []  # list of keys from every section
    for section in self._sections:
        self._section_keys.extend(self.parser_dict[section].keys())

    #----------------------------- Cosmetics ---------------------------
    self.winfo_toplevel().title(self.window_title)
    self.container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container)
    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(
        master=self.container,
        orient="vertical",
        command=self.canvas.yview
    )
    self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

    # make a LabelFrame for each section in the ConfigParser
    for section in self.parser_dict.keys():
        frm = tk.LabelFrame(self.scrollable_frame, text=section.title())
        frm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frm.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # make a label and Entry/Text widget for each key in the section
        for idx, section_key in enumerate(self.parser_dict[section].keys()):
            self._section_keys.append(section_key)
            frm.grid_rowconfigure(idx, weight=1)

            tk.Label(frm,
                text=section_key.title(),
                anchor='ne',
                width=self.label_width
            ).grid(row=idx, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='e')

            # the length of this particular value
            val_len = len(self.parser_dict[section][section_key])
            # if the key has a long value put it in a scrolledtext
            if val_len >= self.max_entry_length:
                ent = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frm,
                    width=self.text_width,
                    height=self.text_height
                )
                ent.grid(row=idx, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='e')
                the_key = self.parser_dict[section][section_key]
                if ',' in the_key:  # check to see if the string is a list
                    the_key = the_key.split(',')
                    for word in (the_key):
                        ent.insert('end', word.strip())
                        if not word in the_key[-1]:
                            ent.insert('end', ',\n')
                else:  # it isn't clearly a list, so just stick it in there
                    ent.insert(1.0, the_key.strip())
            # use an entry widget if the key's value is short enough
            else:
                ent =  ttk.Entry(frm, width=self.entry_width)
                ent.grid(row=idx, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='e')
                ent.insert(0, self.parser_dict[section][section_key])
            # after deciding which to make, add to a list for convenience
            self._fields.append(ent)
        # finally, pack the LabelFrame for that section
        frm.pack(pady=5, padx=5, anchor='sw', fill='both', expand=True)

    # make buttons to save the form or reset to defaults
    btnfrm = tk.Frame(self.scrollable_frame)
    ttk.Button(btnfrm,
        text='Save',
        command=lambda: self.save_config()
        ).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=3, sticky='ne')
    ttk.Button(btnfrm,
        text='Reset Defaults',
        command=lambda: self.reset_config()
        ).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=3, sticky='nw')
    btnfrm.pack()  # put them at the bottom of the form

    # then pack everything else
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0),
        window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw"
    )
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    #-------------------------------End Cosmetics---------------------------------

    # set bindings to enable scrolling
    self.scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda event: self.canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
        )
    )
    self.canvas.bind_all(
        '<MouseWheel>',
        lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(
            int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"
        )
    )

def reset_config(self):
    """Rebuilds the ConfigManager from the defaultdict."""
    print('Rebuilding form from defaultdict')
    self.build(self.defaultdict)

def save_config(self):
    """Saves the contents of the form to configpath if one was passed."""
    # collect all the inputs
    all_inputs = []
    for child in self._fields:  # filter getting by widget class
        if isinstance(child, ttk.Entry):
            all_inputs.append(child.get())
        if isinstance(child, tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText):
            text = child.get(1.0, 'end')
            all_inputs.append(text)

    new_parser_dict = {}
    for section in self._sections:
        new_parser_dict[section] = {}
        for section_key, input in zip(self._section_keys, all_inputs):
            if section_key in self.parser_dict[section]:
                # configparser uses ordereddicts by default
                # this should maintain their order
                new_parser_dict[section][section_key] = input

    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read_dict(new_parser_dict)

    if self.configpath is None:
        print(f'Not saving to file because configpath is {self.configpath}')
    else:
        with open(self.configpath, 'w') as configfile:
            parser.write(configfile)

    # reset the form to reflect the changes
    self.build(new_parser_dict)

def as_dict(self, config) -> dict:
    """
    Converts a ConfigParser object into a dictionary.
    The resulting dictionary has sections as keys which point to a dict of the
    sections options as key : value pairs.
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944270
    """
    the_dict = {}
    for section in config.sections():
        the_dict[section] = {}
        for key, val in config.items(section):
            the_dict[section][key] = val
    return the_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.menubar = tk.Menu(root)
    root.menubar.add_command(
        label='Settings',
        command=lambda: ConfigManager(root)
    )
    root.winfo_toplevel().config(menu=root.menubar)
    root.winfo_toplevel().title('ConfigManager Demo')
    tk.Label(root,
        text='Your stuff here', anchor='center'
        ).grid(padx=100, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I updated your code and pointed it to my ini file that my python3 code uses. When I run the program I get a similar output of the Config Manger Demo window. perhaps my ini file is too long.